# Analytics tool for Excel data analysis

Tags: java, spring-boot, analytics, data-analysis

I want to use a analytics tool to integrate in my spring boot application where I will be uploading an Excel sheet and the tool will determine the columns to create reports or charts. Which tool will be best for it?

I tried to find tools but got confused after reading their API documentation.

Comment: For data science, you can use python. If you can use api which communicate with python and create module using matplotlib and pandas(These are libraries in python) and work with them and at the end you can get export image of charts and data in raw.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.